# Can 32-bit assembly code be ran on a 64-bit processor? (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, assembly

I am writing a program in Delphi, and including a library which contains some assembly code (Pipes.pas).  I am getting an access violation when I run the code which makes a call to a function called StdWndProc.  The process is an assembly function which contains assembly code.

A while back I updated this code (Pipes.pas) to include unicode support and other stuff, but I didn't figure out what this assembly was doing.  Any ideas on what's going wrong here?

I'm running on a 64-bit machine, could it be that this assembly is 32-bit and isn't running correctly on a 64-bit processor (the project is targeted at 32-bit build).

Comment: If you're compiling for a 32-bit application, 32-bit assembly should work fine there are major portions of the Delphi RTL that use 32-bit assembly in 32-bit targets. It obviously won't work if you're targeting a 64-bit build and trying to use a 32-bit library. Can you [edit] your question to provide the *exact* error message you're getting? "I am getting an access violation" is entirely too vague to be of use.

Comment: I have an awful suspicion... Which version of Delphi are you using to compile your code? Is it the same that you used to create the code? Note, that in Delphi 2009 the Unicode support became the default option, so migrating old Delphi code to versions after 2009 needs some extra work. For more information on this see [link](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/40307)

Comment: Please include a tag on what Delphi version you are using. If possible, also be more specific on your problem: under what circumstances does it crash, and under what circumstances does it work correctly. Did you write `pipes.pas` yourself, or only change it?

Comment: The only time I've run into problems of 32bit code being run on 64bit OS...is when making some Windows Security API calls...when Windows changed the underlying data structure (from 32 bit to 64 bit structure) but didn't give any way to send or change the data structure... http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920754

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A 32 bit process executes 32 bit code. It doesn't matter whether that code was compiled from assembler or Delphi or some other language.

It doesn't matter whether the machine is 64 bit or 32 bit, a 32 bit process runs 32 bit code. On a 64 bit machine, a 32 bit process runs in an emulated 32 bit machine called WOW64.

Conceptually what you are attempting is possible, so the conclusion is that your code has a bug.

Answer (score 2):

As **David Heffernan** pointed out the cause of your problem can hardly be the OS architecture.

If your code runs with no errors on 32 bit machines, but it fails to run on 64 bit ones, it could be an OS issue however. It could be caused because of the use of 32 bit-exclusive directories (like *SD:\Program Files* which is called *SD:\Program Files(x86)* on 64 bit windows for 32 bit programs), registry reflection (which causes your program to store registry data under the *Wow3264Node* key), or even the use of old 16 bit **DLL** s (that can not run under wow3264), but that is a very rare case since it is 2013...

To be able to help I need further details of **how** your code *does not run correctly*.

**(Please note, that the original question is already answered, I only wanted to provide some more useful help.)**